# Is .hasOwnProperty() necessary with for..in in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, prototype, javascript-objects

When I do `for..in`, can I dispense with the `if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {...}` check in Node.js if I am careful never to modify `Object.prototype` myself?

Or if I `require()` some third party package that happens to modify `Object.prototype`, does that screw up the `Object.prototype` for my module too?

Comment: Any third party library might put additional properties or methods on Object.prototype. You should NEVER assume that this will never happen. So I would say that it's better to let your "if". Object is common for all modules. It would be very strange to have different types of "Object" in different parts of your javascript code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I dispense with the if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {...} check in Node.js if **I am careful** never to modify Object.prototype myself?

No, because Object is global. Anyone that messes with it in any module you use (or, any module they use by proxy) and they've broken it for your code regardless of what you do. The property check is damage control. It's a check on the nature of someone mucking with you're implicitly inheriting from.

## node_modules/breakit.js

```
Object.prototype.foobar = () => "borked";
module.exports = true;
```

## run node..

```
> require('breakit');
true
> let a = {};
> for ( let k in a ) { console.log(k) }
foobar
> a.foobar();
borked
```

It's important that while the `.hasOwnProperty` is necessary for the *for .. in* loop, the loop itself is probably not necessary and better avoided in most cases. The [air-bnb eslint style guide for instance bans looping over an object all together](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/issues/851).

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing specific in node that would warrant not having this check.  If you are already using lodash you can use _.forOwn() https://lodash.com/docs#forOwn

Another option is:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(yourObj)
.forEach(function(keyName) {
  yourObj[keyName] // do stuff
});
```

Or continue doing the 'if' check, there's a few options, but I would definitely keep one of the checks in, your choice which.